# What Regex code can I use in php to get rid of these symbols? ${}

Tags: php, regex

I need to get rid of ${} but leave anything between the brackets with a regex replace with php. to be more precises want to take out opening ${ and closing } and leave everything else as is in the string.

for example if i have a

```
string = "here is part one ${anything453*@else inhere} and here is part two"
```

I want to get a

```
string = here is part one anything453*@else inhere and here is part two
```

or if I have a

```
 string = ${}
```

I want to get a blank string.

I tried this and get an empty string

$string =preg_replace('/${\}/', '', $string);

Comment: Can you please post an actual example and what you have tried so far?

Comment: You should edit your question to include a sample string of data and the result set of matches which you need. If possible, also include what regex you have tried and explain which part fails. As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: Do you ever expect multiple instances of `${}` such as `$string = '${tihs} and ${that}';`? Or what would you expect from `$string = 'hey there ${s{o}methi}ng';`. Or what if `$` is not the first character like `$string = ' hello ${hey} 9frfg';`

Comment: What should happen with `$string = 'some text here${this thing ${another} thing} more text';`?

Comment: What if there is a space after the opening bracket? `$string = 'text ${ here } and there';`

Comment: hi if there are multiple instances they should all go away and if there is a bracket within a bracke the brackets inside can stay.  if there is a space after the bracket the space stays .  if there is a ${ within a bracket that has to go also.

Comment: i modified my example in the code

Comment: @Diana What does "go away" mean? You should add my examples to your question and present the expected output. Why does this have to be a game of pulling teeth?

Comment: hi monkey zeus, sorry , when i say go away i mean replace with "" or replace with nothing

Comment: It's simple really, sit in a loop while replace all is true use `(?s)(\${((?:(?>(?!\${|}).)+|(?1))*)})` and replace with `$2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove ${ and } from string, you should use alternation in regex and use this,

```
\$\{|}
```

and replace it with empty string.

Try this sample PHP code,

```
$str = 'here is part one ${anything453*@else inhere} and here is part two';
$str = preg_replace('/\$\{|}/', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

This outputs following string,

```
here is part one anything453*@else inhere and here is part two
```

I know this question can be broad as you haven't mentioned what should happen in various possible cases, so if you want specific cases to be dealt particularly in specific ways, please add more examples for input string vs expected output string.